# Why can't i change the background color in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser

what is wrong with my code? i'm using game.stage.backgroundColor but the screen remains black.

main.js:

```
var demo = demo || {};

demo.game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, '');

demo.game.state.add('state1', demo.state1);
demo.game.state.add('state2', demo.state2);    

demo.game.state.start('state1');
```

state1.js:

```
var demo = demo || {};

demo.state1 = function() {};

demo.state1.prototype = {
    preload: function() {

    },
    create: function() {
        game.stage.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";
    },
    update: function() {

    }
};
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that all the functions actually run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I did some tinkering with Phaser, and found the following code to work. Basically it seems like your issue was that the state doesn't know what the variable `game` is. That created an issue. The issue wasn't in setting the color, the issue was that code never got called. Anyways, here's the code that worked for me.

```
var demo = demo || {};

var stateOne = function(game) {
}
stateOne.prototype = {
    create: function() {
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#FF00FF";
    },
}

demo.game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, "");
demo.game.state.add("stateOne", stateOne);
demo.game.state.start("stateOne");
```

As a disclaimer I should probably mention that I am not very experienced in JavaScript, so if you feel like some part is not necessary, feel free the point that out (or just remove it, you know it better).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the background color for the whole game, it´s easier to just set it in the game config. You can even use transparency:

```
const config = {
  ...
  transparent: true
  ...
};
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

...and with a color:

```
const config = {
  ...
  transparent: true,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,110,110,0.5)',
  ...
};
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```